# Ubuntu 18.04 desktop - Best backup strategy for laptops and desktops

Tags: backup

I've got (what I think) is a rather simple question for backing up an ubuntu-desktop.

There are many posts about this and I see a number of references to software that's no longer in development, etc... So, I thought I'd post here for any up to date smart tips and tricks the community use since it seems I'm looking for more from my backup plan.

My experience so far...

I've used timeshift for the last several months and restored my system successfully from local copies perfectly countless times. It's been absolutely amazing, but I'm not happy with a few areas and looking for ways to do a bit more

My list of issues:

1. Being forced to use the root of any partition I give it - Not being able to back up to two different locations (I'd like at least one additional copy sent to a USB drive that I can run with a command as and when necessary)
2. A limitation of a single backup location - can't have a local and USB drive copy
3. Limited command line ability

Ideally, I'd like to find a decent single application alternative that can do the following:

1. Full live system backups with monthly and incremental snapshots (as timeshift does)
2. File and folder backups such as Deja Dupe (Something with nautilus integration as Deja Dupe would be pretty amazing)
3. Most importantly - Ability to use the command line to backup to an alternative offsite location - i.e. a USB drive

I could, of course, use timeshift for live backups and Deja dupe for the file and folder bit if options are really limited - in which case then I'd need a decent and low resource usage command line solution for piping live systems backups and snapshots to a folder on a USB hard drive.

Any good suggestions please people?

I'd also be interested in hearing about what you do to secure the system and your files on your system. Perhaps what I am asking for is either too much or misguided in some way.

Thank you

UPDATE: I guess if I had setup the drives with LVM this would be a far easier question to answer.

Comment: Do you seek a single application that can perform all 5 of your requirements?

Comment: You are likely correct. Perhaps this post should rather be more open to an expert opinion on the best backup strategies and services to use for backing up a desktop with timeshift like features.

i.e 

1 - Live system backup with incrementals so I can roll back the desktop if needed.

Comment: What's working for me right now is: 

[ #1 - Live system backup with incremental snapshots so I can roll back the desktop if needed. This is an absolute must ]

[ #2 - I like Deja dupes ability to roll back files and folders - but I have /home on a separate partition anyway (I know a disk failure is possibly an issue one day as well with this) and I like its integration into Nautilus ]

Comment: What's annoying me is Timeshift's limited command line abilities and simple features. In addition to what it offers, I'd like to be able to issue a command and backup a full or incremental snapshot to a USB drive in  particular folder  as well as keep a local copy on a sperate partition

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1170801/edit) your question to include your thoughts. Don't bury important information in comments. Comments are merely intended to help you refine and improve the question. Be sure to include criteria by which you will judge the answers - else all the answers will simply be opinion-based.

Comment: Gotcha - Question updated...

Comment: Borg is a simple, flexible, commandline backup solution https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/  I have a few sets in my crontabs -- the root crontab and my user's.

Comment: Tks Stephen - I've got that on the go now and it looks like it'll do the job nicely

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's a good back-up strategy for 1 desktop PC?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)